Copy vertices and keep their UV coordinates
Guys!
I have a 3d model with hight count of chaotic polygons.
I want to make a new model with less polygons count.
Let's say I select 4 vertices(see schreenshot) and I want dublicate this vertices to make Face from vertices, so I had only one face, based on this 4 vertices. And I want to keep the same UV coordinates for this vertices so the texture fits the same as on original one model. But after I dublicate vertices, their UV coordinates are lost. Any idea how could I copy the vertives and keep the same UV coordinates for them? Thanks!


In blender vertices don't hold uv because they aren't doubled on uv seams. You could split edges on seams to then store uv on verts but I think what you really want is to use data transfer modifier

I think you could also get pretty far by using a Decimate modifier, set to Planar with the degree at like 1-3 degrees, and Sharp and UVs checked in the Delimit section. This will get rid of a lot of your redundant geo basically for free and should mostly keep your UVs unpeturbed. But yeah other than that I think it's what Markus was saying, Data Transfer modifier onto a LP mesh or baking the diffuse to a LP with completely new UVs.

@Jakemoyo bake to completely new UV sounds good, but what if I have not only diffuse map but Normal Map and ORM also, how can I bake it all to new UV? Thanks for your reply.

AFAIK you can bake normals like you typically would with a normal map applied to the "HP". It should transfer. You could try just applying the ARM as a diffuse and baking it that way, but that might bring up issues with color space/transform so be careful. I would try the Decimate or Data Transfer technique before doing this honestly, in that order. Decimate is the real brainless method that has like a 50% chance of failing, but will take like 20 secs tops. DT is a bit more complex, but would be cleaner than decimating. Baking is the no-other-choice option.

@Jakemoyo Thank you! I've set normal map as normal map and have baked normals so it works perfect. ARM I've set as diffuse and it also works. So I fully optimized the model and rebuild all the textures. I tried decimate and data transfer but I dont like the result even if takes less time.
